# Hyperlink to homepage after author in amsart

Tags: etoolbox, amsart, hyperlink

The amsart class provides the command `\urladdr` which is intended to place a hyperlink to the homepage of each author at the end of the document. I wonder whether the amsart `setauthors` command can be modified so that an icon appears after each author on the titlepage which links to his/her homepage. Something similiar is for instance implemented here

https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/7D104EEB4C57022750BB614A0FBCD73C/S2050508619000088a.pdf/primes_represented_by_incomplete_norm_forms.pdf

I am aware that a cheap hack to do this is to include the hyperlink directly in the entry of the `\author` command. This is not what I am looking for. The functionality I have in mind is that I can throw all extra code into a new latex package and then switch back to standard amsart by simply not loading the package. I suspect this might be possible using the etoolbox package, but I could not make things work.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.  It's worth sending this inquiry/request to the AMS: tech-support@ams.org .  I'm pretty sure, though, that the traditional journal/editorial style won't allow that on the first page of an article.

Comment: For something you could hack into `amsart` for your own use, you could try to enter `\url{...}` into a `\thanks` item; only one per author, but you could tack it on to an existing one after `\endgraf` (`\par` isn't allowed in footnotes).

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather not use a hack for a variety of reasons.

Comment: The suggestion to use `\thanks` is not a code hack; it doesn't touch `amsart` or redefine anything at all, but takes advantage of an available user-level command.  I realize that the outward form of what I suggested is rather different from what you describe.  (I still consider it a "hack" because it's using something that wasn't meant for that particular purpose.  But I think you meant hack in the code sense, at least as you describe it in the question,)

Comment: The information about your desired functionality could usefully be incorporated in your question.  Clearly, I misinterpreted that part.

Comment: Ok, good point. I did as you propose.